# Get DOMNodeList of elements with only the given class

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, domdocument

I am parsing a 3rd party HTML page using PHP DOMDocument and DomXPath.
I use the following code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html);
$dom->encoding = "UTF-8";
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
```

Now there are several elements using the same class, but I want to target the one that uses **only** the given class, for example:

```
<table class="tbl"></table>
<table class="tbl red"></table>
<table class="tbl large blue"></table>
```

I use the following selector:

```
$classname = "tbl";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
```

Which, of course fetches all three tables given above. Is there a simple way to get only the first one?
Thanks

Comment: Why you load HTML with a xml declaration?

Comment: BTW, you can use this pattern: `(//*[contains(@class, '$classname')])[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

Note that with your XPath query you can access to desired node by this way:

```
$nodes->item(0);
```

To select only the first node you have to modify your pattern in this way:

```
$nodes = $finder->query("(//*[contains(@class, '$classname')])[1]");
```

But to access to desired node you need anyway to use this syntax:

```
$nodes->item(0);
```